# Flip view and increase view's size simultaneously (iOS)

Tags: ios, uiview

I am successfully able to flip a view using the following code:

```
UIView.transition(from: firstView, to: secondView, duration: 1, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.transitionFlipFromRight, completion: nil)
```

However, I would like to increase this views height while the animation is occurring.  Is this possible?

I tried animating the height before transitioning, but it does nothing:

```
//original height is 300.0
firstViewHeightConstraint.constant = 600.0 
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
    self.view!.layoutIfNeeded()
})

UIView.transition(from: firstView, to: secondView, duration: 1, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.transitionFlipFromRight, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to call the other overload of [UIView.transistion](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622574-transition) on the superview of the two views in question and manually animate out and in the views.  For the new view you have to composite the flip rotation and the scale into a single matrix, set it as the initial transform and then animate to identity and for the old view do you do the inverse.